# productbuild: add third-party product archive to installer?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, pkgbuild, productbuild

I need to make Mac OS app installer, which also installs other third-party package.

When trying to add it via productbuild --synthesize, it tells "ThirdPartyPackage.pkg is a product archive, not a component package".

So, how should I correctly insert third-party product installer into my installer?

Comment: Were you able to include product package to your own installer?

Comment: It is not possible since final product packages cannot be included to other product packages. So I ended up with two solutions 1) unpack installer package and install lower-level packages in my installer 2) run the whole installer silently from the my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually split up a "product archive" into its component packages by using:

```
pkgutil --expand your_product_archive.pkg some_folder
```

This will create the `some_folder` directory with the contents of the product archive.

Comment: Yeah, but actually the issue was that product package cannot be included to other product package. See my comment on question.

Comment: Pretty sure the meaning of this answer is that once the product archive is split into component packages, you can then add those packages together using `productbuild`. Of course the expansion may show complexities with the distribution and script which you will have to take into account in your installer.

Answer (score 0):

If the third-party archive is reliably available for download, then you could have a post (or pre) install script use `curl` to fetch it (probably into `/tmp`) and `installer` to install it.

Error handling with `curl` is a little janky, since it tends to report no error for lots of errors: 404 not found, domain not resolved, etc. You could just assume it worked, and count on `installer` to error out if there's not an actual package where you tried to download it.